# How to sort by custom column in users section in worpdress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 custom columns in users section in word press "Store name" and " Date" These 2 are saved in users_meta table in DB , How can i show data in User admin list sorted by "Store Name" and then by "Date". My current code till now to add column heading and fetching them from user_meta in users section is as follow.

**Themes Function.php**

```
/* Adds a store name and date column to the user display dashboard.
*
* @param    $columns    The array of columns that are displayed on the user dashboard
* @return           The updated array of columns now including zip codes.
*/
function theme_add_user_Store_name_column( $columns ) {

 $columns['Store_name'] = __( 'Store name', 'theme' );
 $columns['DATE'] = __( 'Date', 'theme' );
 return $columns;

 } // end theme_add_user_Store_name_column
 add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'theme_add_user_Store_name_column' );
 /**
* Populates the store name and date column with the specified user's store name.
*
* @param    $value      An empty string
* @param    $column_name    The name of the column to populate
* @param    $user_id    The ID of the user for which we're working with
* @return           The store name associated with the user
*/
function theme_show_user_Store_name_data( $value, $column_name, $user_id )   {

 if( 'Store_name' == $column_name ) {
     return get_user_meta( $user_id, 'Store_name', true );
 }

 if( 'DATE' == $column_name ) {
    return get_user_meta( $user_id, 'DATE', true );
 }// end if

 }  
 // end theme_show_user_Store_name_data
 add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'theme_show_user_Store_name_data', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on PHPExpert's answer below, as of Wordpress 4.4 you can use `users_list_table_query_args` instead of `request`:

```
// Register the column as sortable    
function Store_name_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['Store_name'] = 'Store_name';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'Store_name_column_register_sortable' );

function Store_name_column_orderby( $vars ) {
    if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'Store_name' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => 'Store_name',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value'
        ) );
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'users_list_table_query_args', 'Store_name_column_orderby', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to sort the users table according to custom meta field, This is used for single column, you can modify it to add second field as well.

```
// Register the column as sortable    
 function Store_name_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
   $columns['Store_name'] = 'Store_name';
   return $columns;
  }

add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'Store_name_column_register_sortable' );
function Store_name_column_orderby( $vars ) {
if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'Store_name' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
    $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
    'meta_key' => 'Store_name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value'
   ) );
 }
 return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'Store_name_column_orderby' );
```

Comment: Please tell Should i add it in theme functions.php or in users.php?

Comment: Please do add this in fucntion.php

Comment: I applied your code it worked but not perfect my store names are like boca, knoxville , orlando so in this case by default it should be in order like boca, knoxville, orlando and when i click it to desc it should reverse the order, currently its comming like knoxville, orlando , boca in desc order and in asc its like boca , orlando, knoxville.

Comment: I have found the issue , actually its sorting on the basis of user name and email as well (wordpress by default) so can u pls tell that how can i ignore them as i want sorting on the basis on my current custom meta columns. "Store_name"